# 12 lead ECG electrode configuration in circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, circuit-design, instrumentation-amplifier, ecg

[image]

I have one little misunderstanding about this diagram, how are the 9 ECG electrodes attached to INAs input legs, as there are even number of them (respectively 10)?

Additionally, I'm not sure where does the Rl electrode goes. Which part of INA is connected to it? And is it only connected to the last INA?

Source: [pdf](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa160a/sbaa160a.pdf?ts=1687440716102&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsolution%252Felectrocardiogram-ecg%253Fvariantid%253D34085%2526subsystemid%253D21999)!

Comment: Page 4 of the linked document tells you what that first block is for and where to find detailed information.

Comment: The 9 ECG electrodes connected to the INAs are LA, RA, LL, and V1 through V6.  The schematic explicitly shows RL connected separately, as RL drive (to control common-mode and keep it within the limits of the instrumentation amplifier)

Answer (score 1):

Two INAs will be used to measure (RA,LA) and (RA,LL), which are two of the sides of Einthoven's triangle.

Then often the three leads RA,LA,LL will be averaged to form a virtual ground which is used as the negative reference for the six INAs measuring precordial leads (V1 through V6).

But it's also completely viable to use RA as the negative reference for all 8 INAs, and correct for the difference between RA and the virtual ground later using digital processing.  The drawback of doing so is that if RA comes disconnected, you lose all leads, instead of only the limb leads.

The schematic explicitly shows RL connected separately, as RL drive (note the direction of the arrow).  RL drive controls common-mode and keeps it within the limits of the instrumentation amplifier.

---

Disclaimer: I haven't read your linked PDF.  I am describing principles of ECG data acquisition which appear to be achievable using the schematic shown in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I just have question about "all 8 INA" part, shouldn't there be 5 of them?

Comment: @NikaAbashidze: The right hand of the diagram shows 8 streams of ADC data.  I don't know why the other section shows 6 INAs (but it *also* shows an ellipsis for more omitted circuitry...)